# Stored procedure and IF statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure in oracle that inserts new data into a table, but before the data is inserted i want it to check if a client is taking treatments that could be conflicting with one another. I have been trying to apply IF statement to get this working, but have been unsucceful, here is the code i have at the moment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FPRESC (
    FP_ID VARCHAR2,
    FTREAT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FCLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FDOC_ID VARCHAR2)
AS
   V_CLIENT_ID PRESCRIPTION.CLIENT_ID%TYPE;
   V_CONFLICT TREATMENTS.CONFLICT%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF (FCLIENT_ID = V_CLINET_ID AND FTREAT_ID = V_CONFLICT)
      BEGIN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONFLICT');
      END;
    ELSE
       BEGIN
         INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION (P_ID, TREAT_ID, CLIENT_ID, DOC_ID)
         VALUES (FP_ID, FTREAT_ID, FCLIENT_ID, FDOC_ID);
END FPRESC;
```

and an example of how i would call the procedure:

```
EXEC FPRESC ('P00011', 'T016', 'C00017', 'D006');
```

Would appreciate some help on what i should change or how i can approach this.

Comment: What's going wrong? Is it a failure to compile? I see you're missing an `END` for the `ELSE` part of your `IF` statement; it should go after the `INSERT` command. Also note that you don't need parentheses around your `IF` condition, but they don't hurt either - go with your preference there.

Comment: IF condition `THEN`
      statement; here `THEN` is missing

Comment: OP, I formatted your query, so if you look clearly, some closing END statement,and THEN after if is missing

Comment: @Aramillo Not very familiar with the use of triggers

Comment: @Ed Yes, the procedure gives compilation errors

Comment: @BhargavModi isnt ELSE and THEN pretty much the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FPRESC (
    FP_ID VARCHAR2,
    FTREAT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FCLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FDOC_ID VARCHAR2)
AS
   V_CLIENT_ID PRESCRIPTION.CLIENT_ID%TYPE;
   V_CONFLICT TREATMENTS.CONFLICT%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF FCLIENT_ID = V_CLIENT_ID AND FTREAT_ID = V_CONFLICT THEN 
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONFLICT');
    ELSE
         INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION (P_ID, TREAT_ID, CLIENT_ID, DOC_ID)
         VALUES (FP_ID, FTREAT_ID, FCLIENT_ID, FDOC_ID);
    END IF;
END FPRESC;
```

Comment: the procedure will not work since you are not assigning any value to v_client_id and v_conflict

Comment: doesnt matter.. its upto the developer to write the correct logic. The error pointed out here was a compilation trouble and this fixes it. I cannot tell the business logic, etc etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FPRESC (
    FP_ID VARCHAR2,
    FTREAT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FCLIENT_ID VARCHAR2,
    FDOC_ID VARCHAR2)
AS
   V_CLIENT_ID PRESCRIPTION.CLIENT_ID%TYPE;
   V_CONFLICT TREATMENTS.CONFLICT%TYPE;
BEGIN
    IF FCLIENT_ID = V_CLIENT_ID AND FTREAT_ID = V_CONFLICT THEN 
      BEGIN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CONFLICT');
      END;
    ELSE
       BEGIN
         INSERT INTO PRESCRIPTION (P_ID, TREAT_ID, CLIENT_ID, DOC_ID)
         VALUES (FP_ID, FTREAT_ID, FCLIENT_ID, FDOC_ID);
       END;
    END IF;
END FPRESC;
```

Comment: This wont compile either.. There is END missing for the BEGIN in the ELSE clause... Also there is no need of separate BEGIN END inside the IF and ELSE if there is no exception handling done.

Comment: it compiled with an error, saying that IF statement is not expected there (PLS-00103)

Comment: @Shankar:- thanks, I modified that, using BEGIN and END , there is no harm

Comment: @user3112130:_ try that now

Comment: Both Piyush and Shankar compiled in the same way. Now i have an error saying identifier V_CLIENT_ID must be declared

Comment: @user3112130: I request you to do some research online to see what an error means when you encounter one. Your error getting identifier must be declared is because when declaring you spelled as V_CLIENT_ID and when using it in the IF Clause you spelled it as V_CLINET_ID.. Please remember, this forum is to help people facing issues after doing research online and not a forum that works like a tutorial center..

Comment: @user3112130: Try to resolve issue first then ask. by the way, check now, it should work now